# Unable to login after switch to Firefox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, firefox

Chrome has been misbehaving recently so I've switched to Firefox. I downloaded and installed Firefox release version 18.0.2 and using that browser I now am unable to login to any Stack Exchange websites. I kept all settings on defaults.

I login via Google, get the necessary prompts, redirected back to Stack Overflow, get the banner saying I have been successfully logged in, however I'm not actually logged in.

Other websites are working fine.

Edit to add: 
**Step 1 - Click 'log in':**

[image]

---

**Step 2 - See auto login banner:**

[image]

---

**Step 3 - Redirected back to main site (Does not look like being logged in):**

[image]

---

**Step 4 - Confirm not logged in by trying to ask a question. Site requests login.**

Comment: I don't see that here; can you log into Google at all?

Comment: I can login to all sites except ones belonging to Stack Exchange.

Comment: You appear to be logged in **here**.. anyway can you post screenshots of what you see?

Comment: I'm using chrome to post here. Will sort some screens using firefox.

Comment: First of all disable any addons/plugins/extensions you have in Firefox, some of those break stuff.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with Firefox at all, it doesn't seem to be mentioned in terms of usage within the body of your question or otherwise included in the problem. After re-reading, I think I understand, but the Q is hardly clear.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: Are you in a trolling mood or serious? There is the tag, the title, and it's mentioned in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: But the site works in Chrome, not in FF. How is that not relevant?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unless one is familiar with current versioning, "Downloaded release version 18.0.2" could be interpreted as either browser after failing with Chrome and further trying with Firefox. The wording is ambiguous. Ultimately, I'm saying this question is unclear for such a report of behaviour; such a thin question would be hell-voted on SO for a technical problem.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: That's just nitpicking now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters From your perspective, perhaps; however, due to my inferiority, or whatever, the ambiguity of the sentences gave me pause. That's indicative of a question that could use improvement, even if just so us lower forms can understand and potentially help.

Comment: Apart from the (successful) banners and all: how can you tell *"I'm not actually logged in"*? Others have reported Firefox problems before, but not with fresh installations I think. Please check [Network Login Troubleshooting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) too, and also ensure your local time is okay. If all seems okay, then you might need to follow the *"if that doesn't work"* part of [Can't log in using Firefox in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow/165469#165469).

Comment: @everyone - I've added screens of what i'm experiencing. Thanks for the question clarification Martijn. To reiterate I am trying to use the AS INSTALLED firefox v18.0.2, no addons, settings changes etc.

Comment: And then clicking "log in" again, gets you the "Welcome back" banner right away? That's exactly what the linked reports are about then, where your Firefox is a fresh installation, so might be interesting to the developers.

Comment: @Arjan - Correct. I can click log in several times and it just loops back and forth from the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Righto. I reinstalled Firefox and this time did NOT import settings from chrome. Everything is now working fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Curious: did you ever try to remove the cache and cookies? I figured that wouldn't help as it was a fresh installation, but I never thought about that import option.

Comment: I don't think I ever considered to clear cache etc as it was a fresh install. It was only on the reinstall that I realized there might be some transfer.

Comment: Aha! I did the same thing - imported Chrome settings. I think it must have imported some of the cookies because clearing all the cookies in Firefox fixes this problem. Clearing the cache won't do - I tried that already.

Comment: Real helpful. Clearing cookies helps.