# Can't login using Firefox 21 Nightly / 19 stable

Tags: bug, openid, login, google, firefox

I am using "Login with Google" and can't access stackoverflow from my account using Firefox. I tested this using 2 versions: At first I tried logging in using Firefox 21 Nightly, then I checked it using the Firefox 19.0.2 stable version (current). It told me that I am logged in with Google and have to refresh the page, so I click at the link and I am logged out. It works well at Chrome, but I would love to have this working with Firefox as well.

Comment: "It told me that I am logged in with Google and have to refresh the page, so I click at the link and I am logged out." -- Who exactly tells you you're logged in with Google, and what link did you click? (Oh, also: no need to test in nightly -- we don't support that anyway)

Comment: I was unable to make a screenshot, but it happens immediately after the login... (unfortunately, it works on meta.stackoverflow.com Oo and it automatically redirects me - I kinda don't have to click a link; I was talking about the small layer at the top of the page after logging in)

Comment: Hmm yeah, the logs confirm your description. Do you have any plugins/extensions installed in your Firefox?

Comment: Yes, some, but disabling all of them and restarting firefox didn't solve the issue. I can mail you my list of plugins if you want, but most of them are simple GUI addons that shouldn't affect the logging-in-process (except for, of cause, Firebug) and it shouldn't help you.

Comment: Btw: I am using official Windows 8 installation on Lenovo Yoga 13 (Germany).

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is this reproducible? If you click "log in", does the "welcome back" bar appear again, and when you reload are you still logged out? 2) If you ignore the "welcome back" bar and click "log in with Google" anyway, does that log you in?

Comment: Both logins fail. Shall I make a small screen video displaying this behavior?

Comment: The only explanation I have is that you have disabled cookies in your Firefox.

Comment: Nope, I do use cookies in Firefox.

Comment: As I said, the page meta.stackoverflow.com works, only stackoverflow.com doesn't

Comment: If you have a moment, can you jump into chat? I'm in the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), just ping me there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I can't because I don't know how to ping someone (:D) and couldn't enter the chat in general as I only have 1 reputation on meta.stackoverflow.com, but you could ping me?

Comment: I am experiencing this as well, using Firefox 19 stable on Windows 7.

Comment: I can confirm this issue, too. Firefox 19.0.2 (arch linux). Cookies enabled. Extensions disabled.

Comment: Same here, Windows XP, firefox with cookies and no extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Although I could originally replicate this issue, I have just **cleared all history** from **tools** -> **Clear Recent History** menus.

It seems appears as though my firefox login is working correctly.

Comment: That's indeed a known problem in Firefox; see [Can't log in using Firefox in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow/165469#165469).