# Can not login to Stack Exchange sites with Firefox nightly builds

Tags: bug, firefox

I can not log into any Stack Exchange sites while using the [Firefox nightly build](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) built today (11.01.2013). When I try to log in, it just says welcome you have been logged in please refresh the page, and when I do that, it says you have been logged in redirecting and it just redirects infinitely.

I already tried deleting all cookies and clearing the cache.

This worked on nightly builds pre 10.12.2013.

What is the explanation?

Comment: Try deleting all cookies; if this doesn't help, you'll need to downgrade to stable.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: i already tried deleting all cookies and clearing the cache i will add this to question

Comment: This won't be investigated. Stack Exchange's official policy is not to support alpha/beta/nightly version browsers. (random linked to the relevant question and answer.)

Comment: You might need to [clear your history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow/165469#165469).

Comment: Similar: *[Can't login using Firefox 21 Nightly / 19 stable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171867)*