# I can't log into Stack Overflow using Firefox

Tags: support, status-norepro, login

I am logging in using my GMail account. From Chrome it works fine:

1. I press login
2. Select Google
3. I am logged in

From Firefox 22.0:

1. I press login
2. Select Google

And I see this at top of the page:

[image]

After another second, I am redirected to the homepage: https://stackoverflow.com/, but I am not logged in. OS Windows 7 SP1 x64 bit.

Comment: Which version of *Firefox* (I assume) are you using?

Comment: FF version is 22.0. I got NoScript add-on (all allowed except adzerk, if i allow adzerk, some banners appear, but problem remains). Also, AdBlock

Comment: Maybe clear the cache, cookies and active logins. `Shift + Control + Delete` in Firefox.

Comment: Niklas, done it, all the same as it was before. Updated flash to 11.8.800.94, same.

Comment: Updated adblock, updated filters, all the same. Turned off AdBlock, nothing changed (except banners appeared).

Comment: Also: login at meta.stackoverflow works fine!

Comment: Updated NoScript, login doesnt works. Turned it off - same.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow/165469#165469)?

Comment: When i open `Shift + Control + Delete` menu, select `Clear all`, select all journal entries, pressing `Clear now`, nothing happens. All history stays. After restart - same. Also, right click on entry at drop-down list from adress bar doesnt spawn any context menu at all. I can `shift-delete` that entry, but when i type same words again in adress bar again, deleted entry appears again.

Comment: What operating system? Are you seeing any javascript errors on the console?

Comment: Same OS and FF versions here. No repro.

Comment: *"All history stays"* -- smells like a broken browser then?

Comment: Maybe your system clock is not updated, by any chance?

Comment: I think history clears after a while. I dont know how i can broke it, i am not even use it for a while, than update it not long ago. And system clock can be +-1 minute wrong :D

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help

Comment: `All necessary browser features are enabled and functioning for network-wide automatic login.

If you still have problems, you might also want to try:

    Clearing your browser cookies for this domain.
    Using a different web browser.
    Temporarily disabling all browser extensions, as some buggy browser extensions have been known to interfere.`
Ive tried to clear cookies, disabled potential trouble-making plug-ins... So, only different browser remains :(

Comment: Again, reading *"When i open `Shift + Control + Delete` menu, select `Clear all`, select all journal entries, pressing `Clear now,` nothing happens. All history stays. After restart - same."* surely describes something that indicates problems with your Firefox. That's out of control of these web sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually deleted stackoverflow cookies after couple reboots, logged in successfully :>