# Is stack exchange login broken at present on Win7/64 bit + Firefox 25.0.1?

Tags: bug, login

I last visited any Stack Exchange sites a couple of weeks ago. This morning, I was not automatically logged in to any site, and had to log in manually. I could not recall my password and had to reset it. Subsequently, each site automatically recognises my login, welcomes me back, but then refreshes me automatically back to the page I was previously on without actually logging me in. The issue does not occur using Chrome as a browser - that is how I am posting this.

Comment: They're [having intermittent issues](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/404941923997081600). I wouldn't worry about it too much for now.

Comment: And Firefox has always behaved a bit differently. Please follow the steps described in [Can't log in using Firefox in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow/165469#165469).

Comment: Thanks Arjan - that fixed it :-)