# SO login does not work with Firefox

Tags: support, bug, login, firefox

I tried to log in at SO, but after entering name and password I get an empty site. When I reload the SO main site, I'm still not logged in.

This is only true for the current Firefox (V26), but not for IE. Cookies are enabled.

Any hints?

I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: Given that you've logged in here, if you go to SO now it still won't work? No "welcome back" or something like that?

Comment: I'm currently logged in with IE, but FF is my Default browser. No "welcome back" with FF.

Comment: Any extensions?

Comment: @Bart: Some. But they are installed since some month. But the described behavior is new since today.

Comment: Okay, perhaps just for the heck of it disable them and see if anything changes. Then we've gotten the usual "did you try turning it off and on again" out of the way. ;)

Comment: I disabled all of them, but no change.

Comment: I have no repro in FF26.0 on win7. Which openid provider are you using?

Comment: @rene: StackExchange, and I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: Ok, I'm using google...

Comment: Did you try clearing the history (and, if that doesn't work, the cache and cookies), as described in [Can't log in using Firefox in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow)?

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, but with no effect.

Comment: @joe Your _entire history for all time?_ (just double checking)

Comment: I'm using Firefox 26.0 (just updated) on Windows 8.1, and I'm using the Stack Exchange provider. I can sign out of and back into SO just fine, in normal browsing and in private browsing. I also get a "Welcome back!" upon signing out and trying to sign back in to MSO.

Comment: @joe do you have cookies disabled?

Comment: Background information: [Requirements for it to work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208) (sub section *What else do I need?*).

Comment: I get failures for the HTML5 stuff but I can't figure out how to fix it. I'm using FF 26 on Linux. All worked fine until a couple of days ago. Now I can't view images and trying to login on meta returns me to the non-meta site. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153107/problems-with-se-site