# Cannot complete signup in Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, sign-up

I recently tried signing up at [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour), and I have a profile. However, in Firefox it always says "complete signing up" and never finishes. On Firefox I have 21 reputation points and in Chrome, which does not complain about finishing signing up, I have 1.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can't have reputation on a browser. Reputation is linked to something called "user account". You can log in to whatever account you want, in any browser you want.

Comment: Anyway... most likely the answers on that other question would work for you too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/cant-log-in-using-firefox-in-stack-overflow.

Comment: Clearing the history and cookies in firefox cleared the issue, however my reputation earned also disappeared :( R.I.P 24 rep. :) Thank you! @ShadowWizard

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reputation disappearing,  you probably logged in to different account. You can ask to merge the accounts, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Comment: Since I was able to answer a question with a "non-completed" profile, i earned some reputation, when i cleared history and cookies, the "complete sign-up" disappeared but so did the rep earned from that answer. @ShadowWizard

Comment: Oh, oops. That means you had unregistered account, cookie based, I didn't get that at first, sorry. I'm not sure the reputation from that account can be retrieved, but if you want and have a link to that account profile page, you can still ask for a merge.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you had two accounts. I merged them for you, so you should be all set with your Information Security rep back in the right place. :)